# Finding a reccurence relation for the following problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A circular disk is cut into n distint sectors, each shaped liek a piece of pie and all meeting at the center point of the disk.  Each sector is to be painted red, green, yellow, or blue in such a way that not two adjacent sectors are painted the same color.  Let $S_n$ be the number of ways to paint the disk.

a) Find the recurrence relation for $S_k$ in terms of $S_{k-1}$ and $S_{k-2}$ for all $K >= 4$

b) Find an explicit formula for $S_n$ for all $n >= 2$

Thanks!

Comment: Can the disk be rotated, or is it fixed? That makes quite a difference...

Comment: I'm gonna assume fixed

Comment: Interesting... I just saw this on a take-home exam (not mine)...

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

Since this question was part of a take home exam, I have temporarily removed the content of my response. I will re-post the content when the exam is through.

**EDIT:**

Below is the original post:

Clearly $S_1 = 4, S_2 = 4*3 = 12$. When forming the pie containing three slices, one can think of shrinking the pie containing two slices so that each slice is now of size $1/3$ and then inserting a new slice somewhere. The new slice goes between the first two, and there are two choices for the color, so $S_3 = 12*2 = 24$.

When inserting the $n^{th}$ slice, $n \geq 4$, there are $n-1$ places it can go (i.e. between the first and second, between the second and third, ..., between the $(n-1)^{th}$ and first), and in each place one has $2$ choices for its color. That gives $2^{n-1}$ choices for a new pie configuration. We have this many new choices for each pie configuration with $n-1$ slices, so $S_n = 2^{n-1} S_{n-1}$.

By the way, another (non-recursive) way to think about this is as follows. Consider the pie with $n$ slices. One can choose $4$ colors for the first slice, $3$ for the second, $3$ for the third, ...., $3$ for the $(n-1)^{th}$, and $2$ for the $n^{th}$ when forming the pie. So the value of $S_n$ should be $8 * 3^{n-2}$ for $n \geq 4$.

Comment: Rookatu, would you consider deleting this answer for a few days? This question is from a take-home exam, and our semester ends in three days.

Comment: Oh! Okay, sure. How does one do that?

Comment: Sadly, I'm not totally sure. There should be a way to rollback to previous content. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again, Rootaku. I flagged the question, but it was declined, with a request for a "link to [the plagiarized question]". Not sure how I am supposed to provide a link to something that is not available online. Oh well.